# imbalanced binary classification with skewed features

Tags: r, binary-data, skewness, unbalanced-classes

I'm attempting to create a supervised binary classification predictive model with about 700K actual cases. The results are imbalanced: 87% negative, 13% positive. There are currently 40 features. Of those, 3 are categorical with fairly balanced distributions. The remaining variables are all ratios with very long-tailed distributions. This example is representative:

```
 category_ratio
 Min.   :  0.0003
 1st Qu.:  0.5916
 Median :  0.9665
 Mean   :  1.3522
 3rd Qu.:  1.4554
 Max.   :782.4587
```

What are recommended modeling approaches in this case? KNN? Naive Bayesian? Logit? Can these or other methods work directly with the skewed variables, or do I have to normalize?

Some of the ratios probably have high collinearity, too, so I need to do some feature reduction. Would RFE be a good approach? PCA? Other?

[For context, there are people on the project with more expertise who are working on finding new features and coming up with other approaches. When I asked, "Has anyone tested what we can do with the data we already have?" the response was, "Feel free to do that." So I'm just looking to make a credible first attempt. Also, I am using R.]

Comment: Curious what you ended up doing for this situation?